# Riak Search 2 not indexing bucket

Tags: python, solr, riak

I'm using Riak as a key-value store backend for a graph database implemented in Python.

I created a custom [search schema](https://github.com/linkdd/link.graph/blob/master/etc/link/graph/schemas/node.xml) named `nodes`.
I created and activated a bucket type `nodes` with the `search_index` property set to `nodes` and the `datatype` property set to `map`.

I inserted the following data into the bucket `default` (with bucket type `nodes`):

```
key: node1
value: {
    "type_set": {"n1"},
    "foo_set": {"bar", "baz"}
}
```

**NB:** the data is automatically transformed into a Map datatype.

I can fetch the data correctly, but I tried the following fulltext searches and no document is returned:

```
type_set:n1
type_set:*n1*
type_set:*
foo_set:*
_yz_rk:node1
_yz_rk:*
```

It seems that my document is not indexed.

I also tried to set the `search_type` property to `nodes` on the bucket `default`, but I got the same result.

The parameter `search` is set to `on` in the configuration file (`/etc/riak/riak.conf`) and the OpenJDK 7 is installed.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, if anyone can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should take into account that Riak automatically adds suffix `_set`, so that you don't have to name yours `type_set` but `type`. Otherwise you will have to query for `type_set_set:*` instead of `type_set:*`.

Second, according to [Data Type Schemas](https://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.0.0/developing/usage/searching-data-types/#data-type-schemas), embedded schemas (as opposed to top-level ones) must use dynamic fields. Apparently Riak prepends field names with some internal identifier of the top-level map. Unfortunately, this also means that you cannot index one set without indexing the other as well.

I've run some tests and found out that `<dynamicField name="*_set" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>` works fine, while `<dynamicField name="*type_set" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>` does not.

Comment: thank you, indeed I misread the documentation, everything's working fine now.